# How to interpret the performance of three python implementations of string reversal

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

I've been programming for about two years at a relatively informal level, that is not needing to care about performance or runtime of my implementations. Now I want to improve my computational rigor by actually computationally analyzing the runtime of my algorithms as opposed to just analytically.

Plotting the runtimes of various implementations of a string reversal algorithm yields results against my expectations.

I implemented four ways of reversing a string in python:

1. Native `string[::-1]`
2. Logarithmic reversal with concatenation (working on a similar principle as mergesort)
3. Logarithmic reversal without concatenation
4. Using loops

Now my expected order of performance in order of runtime `native < log-pure < log-concat < loop`

Here's my graph of performance (note algorithm (1) is too fast to be seen on this scale)

[image] 3

What you see here is that the order of performance (on a logarithmic scale) is `native < loop < log-concat < log-pure` which is inconsistent with the expectation of:

- Loop: `O(n)`
- Log-concat: `O(nlogn)`
- Log-pure: `O(logn)`
- Native: ?

I really don't understand why I'm getting the results I'm getting.

**Using native functions**

```
def native_reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
```

**Concatenative Logarithmic Reversal**

```
def naive_fastreverse(string):
    strlen = len(string)

    # The recursion base case
    if strlen==1: 
        return string

    mid = ""
    a = strlen/2
    b = a

    if strlen%2==1: #i.e. strlen is odd
        mid = string[strlen/2]
        b+=1
    # else:
    #   use no mid letter
    #   use default b

    half_a = string[0:a]
    half_b = string[b:strlen] 

    return naive_fastreverse(half_b) + mid + naive_fastreverse(half_a)
```

**Non-Concatenative Logarithmic Reversal**

```
def optimized_fastreverse(string):
    final = list(string)
    strlen = len(string)

    def computenode(start, end):
        if end-start==1: 
            final[strlen-end] = string[end-1]
        else: 
            computenode(start,start+(end-start)/2)
            computenode(start+(end-start)/2, end)

    computenode(0, strlen)
    return ''.join(final)
```

**Loop Based Reversal**

```
def loopy_reverse(string):
    final=list(string)
    strlen=len(string)
    for i in xrange(strlen):
        final[strlen-i-1] = string[i]
        final[i] = string[strlen-i-1]
    return ''.join(final)
```

Here's my drawing code:

```
import time
import math
import random
import string
import numpy
Num = 5
def rand_str_gen(N):
    return ''.join(
        random.choice(
            string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) 
        for _ in range(N))

randstr = "a"*(10**Num) #rand_str_gen(10**Num)

def run(reverser, reversable):
    start = time.time()
    reverser(reversable)
    end = time.time()
    return end-start

def profile(reverser):
    xs = np.arange(1,Num+1,0.1)
    ys = []
    for i in xs:
        ys.append(run(reverser,randstr[1:int(10.**i)] ))
    return xs ,ys

functions = [
    native_reverse,
    naive_fastreverse,
    optimized_fastreverse,
    loopy_reverse]

reversers = {
    # Makes the function names look nice 
    (" ".join(
        map(lambda s: s.capitalize(),
            func.__name__.split("_")))): profile(func)
    for func in functions}

%matplotlib inline
lengths = ["$10^%d$"%i for i in range(Num+1)]

from pylab import *
fig = figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)  
plots = [
    ax.plot(*data, label=name)[0] 
    for (data, name) in zip(reversers.values(), reversers.keys())
]

legend(handles=plots,loc=2)
ax.set_title("Algorithm Runtime (ms) by String Length")
ax.set_xticklabels(lengths)
```

Comment: Why do you think a single line of code will be slower than a dozen lines?

Comment: I clarified the ordering. It is from smallest to largest runtime.

Comment: Oh, you just expected `log-pure` to be slower than `log-concat`? I must have misread; sorry.

Comment: Not sure where you got that: `native < log-pure < log-concat < loop` is the ordering. log-pure is expected to be faster (smaller runtime)

Comment: Just as a side note, you do not need to fiddle around with the mid element in your Concatenative Logarithmic Reversal implementation, you can remove that if statement in the middle.

Comment: Also, in your Loop Based Reversal, you only need to loop `strlen / 2` times, the second half of that loop is redundant.

Comment: Yes – I see that. But it still should grow linearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not measuring the performance ofthe algorithm, but the behavior of the memory. Due to the multiple cache levels in a PC, there are difference regimes with very different access times. This makes practice completly diverge from theory.

And you are also timing the Python intepreter at the same time, which also distorts the results in an unknown way.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. So do you have an idea how I can measure the time to unify practice and theory?

Comment: @theideasmith This is actually impossible as theory assumes a RAM model, i.e. constant time memory accesses, which does not occur in real-world computers. You may, however improve the accuracy by repeating the same execution several times in a row and ignoring the outliers. You should also use a compiled language with static data structures.

Comment: @theideasmith: another approach to check the behavior is by using counters for the basic operations that you algorithm uses, rather than timing.